# Fetch request to order conversations by date of most recent message

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I have a core data model which has a Conversation entity, and a Message entity. A Conversation will have a one-to-many relationship with Message objects, like this:

```
Conversation:
    messages: many Message

Message:
    sentDate: NSDate
    conversation: one Conversation
```

Hopefully this makes sense.

What I want to do is to list all conversations, ordered by the message with the most recent sent date in each conversation.

Is there a single fetch request I can perform that would do this?

Comment: How do you fetch? You can use a `NSSortDescriptor` to add to your fetch.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using the relationship and a MAX aggregate on the date.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest
    fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Conversation"];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor
    sortDescriptorWithKey:@"messages.@max.sentDate"
                ascending:NO]];
```

Comment: This produces an error `Keypath containing KVC aggregate where there shouldn't be one; failed to handle messages.@max.sentDate`.